# How to center a form in bootstrap 4.1

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am new to Front end.... I would like to centre a form .

I just done it by using  .

But my lead inform me that it is not the right practice .

So is there any way to centre this form .
This is bootstap 4.1.0

I can see that "mx-auto" for spacing in the bootstrap documentation . But it's also not work in this case .

So I am confused how to do it. I just want to align the form to centre in medium and large devices . There is no need to centring in mobile devices.

Thank you

```
        <form method="post" id="new_regform">
            {% csrf_token %}

            <div class="row R1">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4" >
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="{{ form.name.id_for_label }}" class="text-capitalize font-weight-bold">{{ form.name.label|title }}{% if form.name.field.required %}<span class="text-danger">*</span>{% endif %}</label>
                        {{ form.name|add_class:'form-control' }}
                        <span class="form-text text-danger">{{form.errors}}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="{{ form.category.id_for_label }}" class="text-capitalize font-weight-bold">{{ form.category.label|title }}{% if form.category.field.required %}<span class="text-danger">*</span>{% endif %}</label>
                        {{ form.caegory|add_class:'form-control' }}
                        <span class="form-text text-danger">{{form.category.errors}}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="{{ form.Owner.id_for_label }}" class="text-capitalize font-weight-bold">{{ form.Owner.label|title }}{% if form.Owner.field.required %}<span class="text-danger">*</span>{% endif %}</label>
                        {{ form.Owner|add_class:'form-control' }}
                        <span class="form-text text-danger">{{ form.Owner.errors }}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="{{ form.Description.id_for_label }}" class="text-capitalize font-weight-bold">{{ form.Description.label|title }}{% if form.Description.field.required %}<span class="text-danger">*</span>{% endif %}</label>
                        {{ form.Description|add_class:'form-control' }}
                        <span class="form-text text-danger">{{form.Description.errors}}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="{{ form.Identitiy.id_for_label }}" class="text-capitalize font-weight-bold">{{ form.Identity.label|title }}{% if form.Identity.field.required %}<span class="text-danger">*</span>{% endif %}</label>
                        {{ form.Identity|add_class:'form-control' }}
                        <span class="form-text text-danger">{{form.Identity.errors}}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="{{ form.Guardian.id_for_label }}" class="text-capitalize font-weight-bold">{{ form.Guardian.label|title }}{% if form.Guardian.field.required %}<span class="text-danger">*</span>{% endif %}</label>
                        {{ form.Guardian|add_class:'form-control' }}
                        <span class="form-text text-danger">{{ form.Guardian.errors }}</span>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="{{ form.Hobby.id_for_label }}" class="text-capitalize font-weight-bold">{{ form.Hobby.label|title }}{% if form.Hobby.field.required %}<span class="text-danger">*</span>{% endif %}</label>
                        {{ form.Hobby|add_class:'form-control' }}
                        <span class="form-text text-danger">{{ form.Hobby.errors }}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="card border-0">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="col-12 pull-right text-right">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary text-capitalize font-weight-bold mr-2 Create" type="submit">Submit</button>
                            <a href="#">Cancel</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: what do you want to center? your form has 3 sections that take the full width and thus could be consider to be centered, do you want to center the text of the form or the button at the bottom?, do you have your form inside of a `.container`?

Comment: `<form class="col-md-8 mx-md-auto">`

Comment: Thanks Bro.... It's working @ Prakash Rajotiya

Answer (score 1):

It could be a workaround, but what I used to do is, divide the entire layout into three columns and include the content to be centered in the middle column, like this.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <form>
           <!-- Your Code -->
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it is as following. Note that this code is the minimum required. The first div is acting like the body. If you want to center something, then you will add another tag such as the `form` or a `div` and do as you wish.

### With CSS :

```css
html, body, #myContainer {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="myContainer" class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
            <form>
                content here
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

### Without CSS :

```html
<html class="h-100">
    <body class="h-100">
        <div class="d-flex h-100 align-items-center justify-content-center">
            <form>
                content here
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make for the center, please use the `.ml-auto, .mr-auto` bootstrap classes.

Answer (score 0):

```
div.form
{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
form
{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: left;
}
```

```
<div class="form">
    <form name="Form1">
        ...
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap then add this bootstrap class which make your form center:

d-flex flex-wrap align-content-center text-center